# How to type a map method with react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, mapping

I'm having a map method and expecting it to return a new array. And I'm having an error

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'

I think it's because I didn't type the map method variables. How can I do it ?

```js
type Props = {
  authors: [];
  onFinish: () => {};
};

    const NewTask: FC<Props> = ({ authors, onFinish }) => {
    return (
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        defaultValue="select"
      >
        <option value="select" disabled>
          Select Author
        </option>
        {authors.map((author) => (
          <option key={author.id} value={author.author_name}>            // author keys are error sublimed
            {author.author_name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      )
    }
```

Comment: You declared `author` as `[]`. You have to specify the type like `number[]` or `any[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you didn't define the type for authors. To fix the error, you need to provide a type for the authors prop:

```
type Author = {
  id: string;
  author_name: string;
};

type Props = {
  authors: Author[];
  onFinish: () => void;
};

const NewTask: FC<Props> = ({ authors, onFinish }) => {
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `author` as having type `[]`.

As a Javascript value, `[]` is a literal empty array, that can have any values added to it.

As a Typescript type, `[]` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) – specifically, it's an empty tuple which can never contain any values of any type.

When you're iterating `authors` ...

```js
authors.map((author) => { ... })
```

... Typescript infers the type of `author` based on the type of `authors`. Since you've declared that `authors` contains no values, it rightly warns you that `author` has the `never` type, hence `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'`.

As other folks have pointed out, you just need to provide an appropriate type for `authors`, e.g.

```js
type Author = {
  id:          string;
  author_name: string;
};

type Props = {
  authors:  Author[];
  onFinish: () => void;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
type Props = {
  authors: [];
  onFinish: () => {};
};

const NewTask: FC<Props> = ({ authors, onFinish }) => {
return (
  <select
    onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
    defaultValue="select"
  >
    <option value="select" disabled>
      Select Author
    </option>
    {authors.map((author, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={author.author_name}>            // author keys are error sublimed
        {author.author_name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
  )
}
```

Or you should check if you are getting the author object with id and author_name keys